# Pointy individual menu items in menukeys

Tags: menukeys

I want something like this:

[image: desired]

but all I can do is this:

[image: actual]

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
When you see \menu{File>Save}, it means to click on the \menu{File} menu item then on the \menu{Save} submenu item.
\end{document}
```

What do I need to do to get the output I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the package does not support these features out of the box. But it uses Ti*k*Z, so it is easy to "hack". For your convenience, I added a command `\Menu`, which takes an optional argument that allows you to add these features. Let me stress that it will be easy to add tons of further features (just let me know) but at the moment the keys are `t>` for the arrow on the right side, and `>t` for the arrow on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{menu hack/.cd,
t>/.code={\tikzset{tw@menus@base/.append style={signal to=east}}},
>t/.code={\tikzset{tw@menus@base/.append style={signal from=west}}}}
\newcommand{\Menu}[2][]{\begingroup%
\tikzset{menu hack/.cd,#1}%
\menu{#2}%
\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\sffamily
When you see \menu{File>Save}, it means to click on the 
\Menu[t>]{File} menu item then on the \Menu[>t]{Save} submenu item.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  Thank you very much for this!  I'll upvote and accept this answer when I am able to.

Comment: @user338955 You're welcome!